# Python Pandas join or shape data to add two new columns with repeated values

Tags: python, pandas

Ok. I have no idea how to actually ask this question but here goes. I have a dataframe like this.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Product' : ['Product_A','Product_A', 'Product_B', 'Product_B'],'Country' : ["DE", "DE", "DE","DE"],'Billed_Week' : ['201652', '201701', '201652', '201701'],'Billings' : [1116, 9030, 7476, 2859]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

sequence = ['Product','Country','Billed_Week','Billings']
df = df.reindex(columns=sequence)
```

output:

```
    Product   Country  Billed_Week  Billings
0  Product_A      DE     201652      1116
1  Product_A      DE     201701      9030
2  Product_B      DE     201652      7476
3  Product_B      DE     201701      2859
```

I need to add two more columns "Billed_Week_New" and "Billings_New" where they  have values added in a repeated format based on the grouping of the entire first dataframe. So for the first record of the first dataframe I need to expand by the number of Weeks in the whole grouping. I will just show with the output required.

Output required:

```
Product    Country  Billed_Week  Billings   Billed_Week_New   Billings_New
Product_A   DE       201652       1116        201652             1116
Product_A   DE       201652       1116        201701             9030
Product_A   DE       201701       9030        201652             1116
Product_A   DE       201701       9030        201701             9030
Product_B   DE       201652       7476        201652             7476
Product_B   DE       201652       7476        201701             2859
Product_B   DE       201701       2859        201652             7476
Product_B   DE       201701       2859        201701             2859
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the cross join, returning Cartesian product between columns (all possible combinations between sets on same key(s) here being *Product* and *Country*):

```
mdf = df.merge(df, on=['Product','Country']).\
      rename(columns = {'Billed_Week_x': 'Billed_Week',
                        'Billings_x': 'Billings',
                        'Billed_Week_x':'Billed_Week_New',
                        'Billings_y':'Billings_New'})
print(mdf)

#      Product Country Billed_Week  Billings Billed_Week_New  Billings_New
# 0  Product_A      DE      201652      1116          201652          1116
# 1  Product_A      DE      201652      1116          201701          9030
# 2  Product_A      DE      201701      9030          201652          1116
# 3  Product_A      DE      201701      9030          201701          9030
# 4  Product_B      DE      201652      7476          201652          7476
# 5  Product_B      DE      201652      7476          201701          2859
# 6  Product_B      DE      201701      2859          201652          7476
# 7  Product_B      DE      201701      2859          201701          2859
```

Comment: /mindblown... I was seriously trying some obnoxiously stupid stuff.  Was just about to post and I see this bit of elegance.  Well done.  BTW `df.merge(df, on=['Product','Country'], suffixes=['', '_new'])`

Comment: Thanks, @piRSquared...even better with assist on the column rename.

Comment: Parfait, thanks man. Also, thanks piRSquared. It all does exactly what I asked and all in one line of code.